# Is possible to write a script to generate sql triggers for each automatically?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, scripting

I have to create triggers for each of my tables that I have in my server. These 3 triggers would be for my table employees for example:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_insert$$
CREATE TRIGGER auditemployees_insert AFTER INSERT ON employees

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees_trigger (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) SELECT emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM employees WHERE emp_no = NEW.emp_no;
END$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_delete$$
CREATE TRIGGER auditemployees_delete BEFORE DELETE ON employees

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees_trigger (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) SELECT emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM employees WHERE emp_no = OLD.emp_no;
END$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_update$$
CREATE TRIGGER auditemployees_update BEFORE UPDATE ON employees

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees_trigger (emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) SELECT emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date FROM employees WHERE emp_no = NEW.emp_no;
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

**The questions are:**

What kind of script/language I can use to generate these triggers for each of my tables?

Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, every table has different columns, how to get it and make it into your scripts sounds impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is possible, You need to declare a cursor the loop through two tables.

```html
 select * from information_schema.tables;
select * from information_schema.columns
```

Then query information_schema.columns for columns names, which is used to compose your create trigger sql as string

Here is my update, but you need to correct some syntax on the result set:
The most important thing is to learn how to concat column names and query the table schema using information_schema.columns table

After the result set as sql statement is returned, copy and run those script.

```html
SELECT 
    CONCAT('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_insert;
            CREATE TRIGGER audit',
            table_name,
            '_insert AFTER INSERT ON ',
            table_name,
            '
            
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ',
            table_name,
            '_trigger (',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')
                SEPARATOR ','),
            ') SELECT ',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')
                SEPARATOR ','),
            ' FROM ',
            table_name,
            ' WHERE id = NEW.id;
            END$$')
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_name IN ('roles' , 'users', 'news')
GROUP BY table_name
```

Comment: Thanks RAY for your answer, just a question, what would be object_id in this case?

Comment: object_id is the id of our table objects.

e.g "select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'employees'

Comment: I am sorry I overlooked that your request is actually mysql. but it can be done using same method. but the query to look up column names is
select * from information_schema.columns 
select * from information_schema.tables;

Comment: I've never used cursors before, so I read a little about them but this seems to be a little more complex than just the basic examples of cursors, anyway, I've come up with this code: http://fpaste.org/329434/43028414/ So in this example I'm doing it with 3 sample tables: users, customers and students. in order to create the (trigger)_insert/update/delete name for the trigger for each table I would have to do something like @tblname_insert? I appreciate so much your help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Saul, I think my previous answer is more complicated, 
but if you learnt how to concat row values from information_schema.columns. then you should be able to compose the create sql very easily

Comment: Just re-write my solution,

Comment: Thank you @RAY for all your help, I'm just hitting some bumps with this solution but looks like what I want to do. As soon as I finish with this problem I will accept your answer :)